# align checkbox and label inside li

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox and its label inside a li like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><label for="first_checkbox_btn">First</label> <input type="checkbox" id="first_checkbox_btn" name="choice" value="" /></li>
    <li><label for="second_checkbox_btn">First</label> <input type="checkbox" id="second_checkbox_btn" name="choice" value="" /></li>
    <li><label for="third_checkbox_btn">First</label> <input type="checkbox" id="third_checkbox_btn" name="choice" value="" /></li>
</ul>
```

What I'm tying to do is align the checkboxes to the far right of the labels inside my li. I tried using float right, but the checkboxes do not stay on the same line as my label.

Any help please.

Comment: Provide your CSS? looks fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/MhsfS/

Comment: It doesn't work with checkboxes

Comment: @user765368 - please show us what you've tried as your minimalistic example above shows us nothing.

Comment: @user765368 Checkbox or radio, both work fine in our case - http://jsfiddle.net/MhsfS/1/. Please do as j08691 said and provide us with an example where it isn't working.

Comment: Why are you using `ul`? By giving checkboxes/radios the same `name`, they are automatically grouped. `Label` is an inline element, you can change it to `inline-block` then float away. While not best practice, you can do `<label for="">blah <input checkbox></label` if your are using CSS to highlight on hover.

Comment: @Zenith The checkbox case does not work in Firefox. With Firefox, the checkboxes are arranged like a staircase.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Which version of Firefox are you using? It's the same on Firefox as it is on Chrome for me.

Comment: @Zenith My version is FF 20 (Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: @OlafDietsche I'm v21, Windows - screenshot - http://postimg.org/image/ao5lgs4d5/

Comment: @Zenith You can see the staircase at the right: http://postimg.org/image/qni3dvfi9/

Comment: @OlafDietsche You're right. This is pretty odd.. hopefully OP will update question with browser details, if he's seeing the same as you, your answer will work

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where it comes from, but if you set the margin to `0`, it works

```
input {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QKQPQ/)

Answer (score 0):

[I put together a quick jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/8XNjH/)

If I'm understanding you right, the above solution will do it. Basically give each `<li>` `position:relative` then set `position:absolute; right:0` on each input.

Of course more information and code would help figure out whats going on.